# Unable to determine driver download file: node-ibm_db

Tags: node.js, npm, db2

I am trying to install `ibm_db` npm module to connect node application to `DB2`. But it is throwing below error:

```
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node installer/driverInstall.js
npm ERR! platform = win32, arch = ia32, node.js version = v16.13.0
npm ERR! Unable to determine driver download file. Exiting the install process.
```

I read on IBM's website that it is not mandatory to download `odbc_driver` before installing `ibm_db`. It automatically downloads the driver by itself. One of my acquaintances installed it successfully without having to download the driver first. But I don't understand why it is failing to download the driver in my case. There is almost no resource on this issue on either github or IBM.

Please help me to identify the exact issue.

Comment: Sometimes the clidriver download site is temporarily unavailable. It is hosted by IBM, unlike the node-ibm_db which is not hosted by IBM. Try downloading and unzipping clidriver manually to see if the site is working for you, from https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/

Comment: I have tried doing this as well. In that case, it installs succesfully, but at the runtime throws some error that it is not able to localte some binding file inside ibm_db module:```Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\myProj\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.node
 → C:\Users\myProj\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Debug\odbc_bindings.node```

Comment: Either way, it is not working

Comment: Verify you unpacked the correct clidriver for your platform and bitness. After you unzip the clidriver, create a system environment-variable IBM_DB_HOME whose value is the fully-qualified name of the directory path containing clidriver. Then open a __new__ cmd prompt, verify IBM_DB_HOME is set in there, and uninstall and re-install the ibm_db, taking care to follow all instructions on the github readme for node ibm_db.

Comment: I have a doubt on this: does the path needs to point to clidriver folder or it should point to the parent directory of clidriver?

Comment: I noticed that the build folder is not available inside ibm_db.

Comment: The directory that contains clidriver (the directory into which you unpacked the zipfile) should be the value of IBM_DB_HOME, and that directory appended to the PATH (to allow commands like db2trc, db2level, db2cli etc to be more easily found) .  For example if you unpacked into c:\ibmdb2\clidriver, then you append c:\ibmdb2\clidriver to the path and give that value to IBM_DB_HOME.